# Erro ao pegar JSON de um texto - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

estou resgatando um `json` de um texto, porém, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.vagas.com.br/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://aerc.postali.com.br' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

segue abaixo a url:

http://www.vagas.com.br/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.vagas.com.br/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {

            }
            });
```

Obrigado.

Comment: O que você quer pegar em especifico? você pode utilizar indexOf para pegar o indice que começa a string e  depois o indice que termina a string e fazer um substring... e por que pegar deste arquivo desorganizado?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues eu consegui pegar o json, so que me ocorre o seguinte erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://cors.io/?u=http://www.vagas.com.br/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://aerc.postali.com.br' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503."

vou alterar a questão

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64695/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olha se você tem acesso ao domínio esse .js deve ser gerado por alguma fonte de dados, recomendo mudar a estratégia, todavia você pode fazer assim (se o js estiver no mesmo domínio que a página):

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
             eval(data);

             var dados = new Vagas().listaDeVagas;

             console.log(dados);
        }
    });
```

Obviamente `eval` pode causar algumas dores de cabeça, mas se usar com scripts do mesmo domínio que o seu e tiver controle sobre eles então pode usar sem temer tanto.

> Recomendo a seguinte leitura: [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/3635)

Se estiver em um domínio diferente será necessário ter o controle do `cross-origin`, isso só se tiver acesso ao domínio de origem do feeds.js, todavia poderá contornar o problema usado uma linguagem server-side.

No caso acho que usa `C#`, eu criei a algum tempo um webproxy em C# pra resolver este tipo de problema, baixe o arquivo `simple-http-proxy-csharp.ashx` em:

- https://github.com/brcontainer/simple-http-proxy-csharp

E coloque no teu servidor, o uso dele é simples:

```
http://your-domain/folder/simple-http-proxy-csharp.ashx?url=http://urlexeterna/feed.js
```

> **Não sei** se tem acesso direto no ASP.NET-MVC, porque eu mesmo nunca usei ASP.NET-MVC, mas acredito que seja possível acessar o `simple-http-proxy-csharp.ashx` diretamente

O uso ficaria algo como:

```
    var url = "http://www.vagas.com.br/vagas/feeds.js?q=engenheiro";
    url = encodeURIcomponent(url);

    $.ajax({
        url: "simple-http-proxy-csharp.ashx?url=" + url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
             eval(data);

             var dados = new Vagas().listaDeVagas;

             console.log(dados);
        }
    });
```

**Devo informar novamente que não é o melhor caminho pra este caso**, seria melhor procurar outra fonte de dados solicitando junto ao T.I. (IT) da empresa que fornece os dados, algo como REST ou SOAP, mas se eles não tiverem tais serviços então a maneira infelizmente é usar um "proxy", tal como citei.